# Breaking cyclic references more elegant in C++

Tags: c++, declaration, forward-declaration, cyclic-reference

I have gotten many cyclic dependencies recently when my header files includes each other.
See also here: [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

I actually do not get totally why its a cycle. When the compiler looks inside the header-file of the include, why does it not recognize the class declaration?

Is there an more elegant/other way to break these cycles instead of a forward declaration of the other class? I do not like that there is a other class declaration in front of my current class. E.g.

```
#include "Wheel.h"  // Include Wheel's definition so it can be used in Car.
#include <vector>

class Wheel;

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};
```

Comment: Option one is getting rid of cyclic references, option two is to just embrace them, option three is to hide all forward declarations in a header and just include that.

Comment: `class Wheel` part is not required, because the compiler needs not only declaration but definition either because of `std::vector<Wheel> wheels` so you can't dodge it with forward declaration.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your `"Wheel.h"` file, but if it didn't contain the full `Wheel` class declaration, this would fail to compile, as your `wheels` variable can't use an incomplete type.

Comment: You haven't _shown_ a cycle, so that part is hard to answer. And, as already mentioned, your existing forward declaration is redundant, as it comes _after_ you include the full definition (and a fwd decl wouldn't be enough to instantiate `vector` anyway).

Comment: I am sorry, but this question cannot be answered here. A true cyclic dependency is when *declaration* of class A would require *definition* of class B while *declaration* of class B also requires *definition* of class A, and is forbidden in C++. Here you have only shown a **direct** dependency. BTW, you need either `#include "Wheel.h` if you need the definition or `class Wheel;` if forward declaration is enough like here. But using both is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I just used the example from the other topic. But in my application I have cyclic dependencies, so I was curious if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got your stuck point.

To explain this, it is better to examine from the view of compiler.

Compiler does for `Car.h`:

- Replaces `#include "Wheel.h"` with its content.
- Replaces `#include <vector>` with its content.

At this step, translation unit for `Car.h` seems like this.

```
class Car;

class Wheel
{
    Car* car;
};

// Vector implementation of the stl goes here

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};
```

At this point, at `Car* car;` line, `class Car` declaration (declaration is enough for pointer types) is needed to define `class Wheel` that's why you need forward declaration because you should tell to compiler that there is a `class Car` and it will be defined soon.

If you comment out `class Car` at line 1 compiler could not know whether there will be a `class Car` or not.

As far as I know there are extra restrictions related with **one definition rule**, maybe someone else might explain that.

It is not possible to have 'more elegant' way for now.

Answer (score -2):

Will can use in each file the directives `#ifndef` ... `#define` `#endif`

So your code will became something like

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include "Wheel.h"  // Include Wheel's definition so it can be used in Car.
#include <vector>

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};

#endif
```

Do it in all your header files, so each file will be loaded at most once and the cycles will not happen anymore

Comment: That doesn't work if there are cyclic dependencies. If there are `Car` usages inside `Wheel.h`, it'd need to forward declare `Car`.

Comment: #ifdef-guards like this are used to prevent repeated inclusions of a header from leading to multiple definition errors. They can't help with cyclic dependencies in definitions, and cyclic inclusions usually indicate that cyclic dependencies are also present.